# Genymotion unable to load template list, no internet connection

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I've just upgraded my Genymotion personal version to the most recent version 3.0.0. However, when I run it, I get an error under the "Available Templates" section that Genymotion is "Unable to load template list, check your Internet Connection."

[image]

Clicking on that "retry" button doesn't work too. My internet connection on my computer is fine, and I'm able to access the internet. But I'm not sure why Genymotion is complaining about my internet connection and it's unable to load the templates. This actually prevents me from creating and running any devices too when the templates section doesn’t load.

I'm running on Virtualbox 5.2.22.

Are there any settings that I have to do to have Genymotion reach my internet connection? How can I get Genymotion to load the template list?

Comment: I got the same issue.
@Carven ... Did you solve it?

Comment: @ViniciusColares Well, unfortunately, I still have this issue. I had to fall back to using avd which is very sluggish most of the time.

Comment: @Carven did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 10):

I also face the same problem but can't find solution on internet,simply  i click on setting 
navigate to Account tab.
Click on sign out.
Login again with my credentials it promote me to ask accept terms and some more steps and 
then it navigate to home screen where all template listing.
Work for me.

Comment: Also Genymotion server lost activation of my email. So I need to went througth the activation process again. After that the app started to work and I saw the templates

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is something wrong in how the new version treats **no-proxy**. I saw in logs that it cannot log-in my user (although my user was already signed in). I signed out and I noticed that I cannot even sign in again!

I activated a temporary proxy and used that proxy before signing in. It signed me in and showed me the templates. I have added a new device and removed the proxy.

I understand that this is not a solution but might help you resolve the issue.

[image: signin-page]

Comment: Just wondering, how did you go about activating a temporary proxy and use that in Genymotion?

Comment: I used the proxy that my company offers, but I guess you can easily find free proxy servers on internet. If your question is how? I just signed out and in the sign in page there was an option to use a proxy server. I filled the information there and set up my new device then I removed the proxy from the settings. I have edited the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

It happen because if you sign in your Genymotion account in another device, you need to sign in again what device you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea as to the cause of the issue but I simply activated a VPN (tunnelbear in this instance) and restarted the app. Got logged in fine and the template list loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the above techniques. Intercepted the response from the server with Burp and noticed an error (it's not visible in the app's GUI, but it's returned from the server). The error message stated that my IP was temporally banned by the site owner.

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled the proxy from the network settings of genymotion and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem,
curiously enough it wasn't proxy related at all, in my case all I did was sign out of genymotion site on my chrome browser and then run the desktop app and it was all good from there.
Hope this helped